# Postgresql user issue

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I have uninstalled and reinstalled postgresql through brew multiple times throughout this whole debacle.

I am trying to transition to using postgresql.app... but whenever I try to start up the program I get an error message and it tells me to check the log.

```
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
LOG:  could not bind IPv6 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
LOG:  could not bind IPv4 socket: Address already in use
HINT:  Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
WARNING:  could not create listen socket for "localhost"
FATAL:  could not create any TCP/IP sockets
```

At this point I don't know what to do... I am trying to delete anything with the a remote semblance to postgresql. Any advice whatsoever would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a linux box? Try executing ps -eaf | grep postgres to see if a process is running. Also try ss -an | grep 5432 to see what is running at 5432.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find which process is currently listening on `localhost:5432`

```
sudo netstat -tpln | grep 5432
```

You'll get the PID. Depending on what it is, you might need to kill it and relaunch your Postgres or identify the program that was running on 5432 to stop it run automatically or remove it.

Comment: So I did have two instances running (one in postgres.app and the other normal). I thought postgres.app required the local files... Thanks a ton!